# How to combine two pivot tables in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, eloquent-relationship

I am stuck in two pivot table and not getting any idea how to do this as I have to display data in Laravel Yajara data table.

First, let me show you my table structure.

```
---------------
Table: projects
---------------
Column          Type
id              int(10)
uid             char(36)
project_name    varchar(255)
created_by      int(10)
updated_by      int(10)
created_at      timestamp NULL
updated_at      timestamp NULL
deleted_at      timestamp NULL

--------------------
Table: group_project
--------------------
Column          Type
group_id        int(10)
project_id      int(10)

-------------
Table: groups
-------------
Column          Type
id              int(10)
uid             char(36)
group_name      varchar(255)
created_by      int(10)
updated_by      int(10)
created_at      timestamp
updated_at      timestamp
deleted_at      timestamp

-----------------
Table: group_user
-----------------
Column          Type
group_id        int(10)
user_id         int(10)

-------------
Table: users
-------------
Column          Type
id              int(10)
uid             char(36)
name            varchar(255)
first_name      varchar(255)
last_name       varchar(255)
email           varchar(255)
phone           varchar(255)
password        varchar(255)
remember_token  varchar(100)
created_at      timestamp
updated_at      timestamp
deleted_at      timestamp
```

In above table structure you can find that, I have two tables(group_user, group_project) which are in relation from project to group and group to user and I want to get records like this.

```
Project 1
    |
    -- Group 1
        |
        -- User 1
        -- User 2
    -- Group 2
        |
        -- User 3
        -- User 4
Project 2
    |
    -- Group 1
        |
        -- User 1
        -- User 2
    -- Group 3
        |
        -- User 5
        -- User 6
```

Here is my code:

```
# Project Controller
public function index()
{
    $projectsObj = $this->project->with(['projectGroups'])->get();
}

# Project Model

public function projectGroups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Groups', 'group_project', 'project_id', 'group_id');
}
```

In the project listing, I want to combine both the pivot table and make a query.

Comment: Can you give your all of the relations with the models. It wiil be helpful for us

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the structure you want.

```php
Projects::with('projectGroups', 'projectGroups.users');
```

If you need to limit the query at all, add constraints to the withs

```php
Project::with([
    'projectGroups' => function($query){
        $query->where('group_name', 'MyName');
    }, 
    'projectGroups.projects' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('project_name', 'my_name');
    }])->get()
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to relate group_user with group_project.

Comment: What do you mean by relate them? Do you want a direct relationship between the User and the Project, or a relationship between the two pivot tables?

Answer (score 0):

In Project model change the relationship as

```
public function projectGroups()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\ProjectGroup', 'project_id', 'id');
}
```

In model GroupProject

```
public function group()
{
return $this->belongsToOne('App\Group', 'group_id', 'id');
}
```

In Group model

```
public function groupusers()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\GroupUser', 'group_id', 'uid');
}
```

In GroupUser model

```
public function users()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'user_id', 'uid');
}
```